# Bottom div is not centered because above div's are taking more space. How to get bottom div centered?

Tags: html, css, codepen

the bottom "credit" div is not centered for some reason , plz give appropriate solution

https://codepen.io/rudrarocks71/pen/qBPgpNQ

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 11s ease infinite;
    height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}

#title {
    color: #f5f6fa;
    padding: 32px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.25;
    display: block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    justify-content: center;
}
#title:hover {
    transform: scale(1.4)
}

#links {
    max-width: 675px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 27px auto;
}

.link {
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    border: solid black 3px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover {
    background-color: #f5f6fa;
    color: #2f3640;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.link:active {
    background-color: rgb(4, 252, 66);
    color: #192a56;
}

i:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

#credit {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WHATSAPP-GROUP LINKS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>


<body>
    <div id="title">
        WHATSAPP-GROUP LINKS
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <a class="link" href="" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;</i>whatsapp
        </a>
        <a class="link" href="" target="_blank">

            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-lg fa-fw"></i>whatsapp
        </a>
        <a class="link" href="" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;</i>whatsapp
        </a>
        <a class="link" href="" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;</i>whatsapp
        </a>
        <a class="link" href="" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;</i>whatsapp
        </a>
        <a class="link" href="" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;</i>whatsapp
        </a>
        <a class="link" href=" target=" _blank ">
            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-lg fa-fw ">&nbsp;</i>whatsapp
        </a>
        <a class="link " href=" " target="_blank ">
            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-lg fa-fw ">&nbsp;</i>whatsapp
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="credit ">
        Made by Rudra Patole FY_B_22

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: remove that single space after ID name! Thats all.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with your HTML. The id `"credit "` has a space after.

replace this:

```
  <div id="credit ">
        Made by Rudra Patole FY_B_22

  </div>
```

with this:

```
  <div id="credit">
  <!-- removed space after credit id (codepen take this like div.credit\)  -->
        Made by Rudra Patole FY_B_22

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex in the credit selector:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```